# Getting the attachment contents of an rtf mail in vsto c#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

we are trying to get the content of the attachment's of the in the rtf mail but I have tried to search using different terms but have not found any reliable solution . can someone please help me to get the source of the attachment's as we get them in the html format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean an embedded object attachment, such as an Excel spreadsheet or an image in an RTF message?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for getting the attachment content. To get the file attached you need to save it to the disk and then read the content from the there.

Also you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. It allows getting the binary data of the attached file. Try using the `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` method while passing in the value "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102" (`PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN`).

```
set msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
set attach = msg.Attachments(1)
set ps = attach.PropertyAccessor
v = ps.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102")
debug.print ps.BinaryToString(v)
```

Comment: its throwing an exception saying that schema is unavailable or unreachable do you have any other solutions for c# can you suggest if any

Comment: You need to save the attached file to the disk and then read the content from there. Another possible option is to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI as I mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

On the low level (Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi), you need to open the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property as `IStorage` and extract the data from there (it depends on the actual type of the attachment). You can see the data in the streams in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the message, click `IMessage` button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the `GetAttachmentTable` tab, double click on the attachment to open it, select the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property, right click, select `IMAPIProp::OpenProperty`, then `IStorage`. Raw data will be there as well as an image representing the attachment (so that Outlook won't have to start the host app when rendering the message).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am also its author, it can be used from any language including C# and VBA), its version of [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` method handles OLE attachments for most popular formats (Word, Excel, bitmap, Power Point, Adobe PDF, etc.) - create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object (using either `CrealeOleObject` or [RedemptionLoader](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader)) and use `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` method (pass either `MailItem` or `Attachment` object) to get back [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) or [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) object respectively.

Answer (score 0):

i have been found a solution for getting the images content from the rtf mail directly whiteout hitting the low level api or anything.
the solution is not a straight forward one

1. save the mail to the disk using oDoc.SaveAs2(filepath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
2. after saving the mail you will get the folder which you save a .htm doc
   now read the .htm doc
3. get the all the image nodes of the .htm doc
4. using the image nods you can get src attribute of the image node
5. using the src value of the image you get the image directly from the disk itself and you can use that image